# How to format the modern Sharepoint wiki like the actual wikipedia, specifically how do we add anchors onto the page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, hyperlink, wiki, anchor-tags

I'm quite new to SharePoint and I need to format the wiki page the same way the original wiki pages look like. Specifically, to be able to click on links and have a content page with anchors to scroll down to the precise information. How can I do that? we are using the modern SharePoint and wiki pages.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For SharePoint Online modern pages, we have automatically-added anchor links in text web parts. The feature is for all first, second and third level headings in your page. Then simply hover over the headings and you’ll see a link symbol.
More information [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/august-2019-updates-to-sharepoint-page-and-news-authoring/ba-p/801482).

For the table of contents, you may need to make it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

second and third level headings in your page. Then simply hover over the headings and you’ll see a link symbol.